# How to properly overwrite `Illuminate\Routing\Router::toResponse` in order to send HTTP status code 204 for empty responses?

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-routing, laravel-response

My Laravel project has a lot of controller methods which simply return nothing or `void` on success. I want (more precisely need) those methods to eventually return a `204 No Content` response to the client. I would like to avoid adding `return response()->noContent()` to each and every controller method where I need it. However, if I do not, Laravel sends an `200 OK` response with an empty body to the client.

The method `Illuminate\Routing\Router::toResponse($request, $response)` is responsible for this. The parameter `$response` equals the return value of the controller method. If the controller method returns nothing, `$response` equals `null`. The method `toResponse($request, $response)` matches the parameter `$response` against different conditions and if nothing matches `toResponse($request, $response)` creates a `SymfonyResponse` with status code 200 and an empty body. I would like to override this method and add another condition. If `$response === null`, then `toResponse($request, $response)` should create a `SymfonfyResponse` with status code 204.

My main problem is that I don't find any information how to make the framework to call my own implementation of the router class.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution which is much easier than overwriting the `Router`. I can use a middleware which modifies the response after the controller method has run, but before the response is sent to the client: a so-called response middleware (see [Laravel Documentation "Middleware $ Responses"](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#middleware-and-responses)).

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

/**
 * Ensures that responses with empty content return status code 204.
 *
 * This fixes a bug in Laravel.
 */
class FixStatusCode {
  /**
   * Handle an incoming request.
   *
   * @param Request  $request
   * @param \Closure $next
   *
   * @return Response
   *
   * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
   */
  public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response {
    /** @var Response $response */
    $response = $next($request);
    
    if (empty($response->getContent())) {
      $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
    }
    
    return $response;
  }
}
```

Then, I have to register this middleware like any other middleware in `App\Http\Kernel::$middleware`.